# VTK wrap for C# on VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, wrapper, vtk

I have got a C++ project built with VTK 5.10.1 and PCL 1.8. I have to rewrite this code in C# using VS2013 so I need to find a way to use VTK on C#. I have found some wrappers like Activiz (http://www.kitware.com/opensource/avdownload.php) but their links do not work, apart from that, I found this wrapper: https://github.com/dgobbi/WrapVTK and I have already built it with Cmake but I do not really know how it works. May anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they just put the wrong URL onto the webpage.

[ActiViz .NET OpenSource Edition 5.8.0  64-bit Windows XP or later](http://www.kitware.com/KWLD/download.php?cid=anonymous&fid=68&pid=17)

[ActiViz .NET OpenSource Edition 5.8.0  Windows XP or later](http://www.kitware.com/KWLD/download.php?cid=anonymous&fid=67&pid=17)

**Update 2018**

new link: [GitHub: Activiz.NET-7.1.1 a .NET wrapper for VTK 7.1.1](https://github.com/dearman/activizdotnet)

There are a lot of examples included and easy to use.

Comment: Your first 2 links are dead.